# marginTop and marginBottom don't work for LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Main(container) LinearLayout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearHome"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Child LinearLayouts (I'm adding them dynamically by inflating new one):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/lnote"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

What's the problem?

Comment: can you provide the code how you are inflating them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412847/linearlayout-relativelayout-etc-margins-do-not-work-as-expected

Comment: `LinearLayout lNewNote = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.note_layout, null);` `HomeContainer.addView(lNewNote);`

Comment: I hat that problem before, but I can't find this place in that project.. In some cases the LayoutParams are lost. Try to set the margins programmatically or maybe to set the second parameter of inflate(R.layout.note_layout, null) to the parent(main container) instead of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the second parameter of the inflate() method to the parent (main container)

```
LinearLayout lNewNote = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.note_layout, HomeContainer); 
HomeContainer.addView(lNewNote);
```

I believe it did the trick for me. (I guess HomeContainer ist an object, not a class)

Answer (score 4):

change the child to this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/lnote"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```